# How can I get Lotus Domino to accept javamail attachments

Tags: java, outlook, jakarta-mail, lotus-domino

I am working on some Java code that implements an 'email log file to support' button.

The code

- Discovers the relevant log files on the client side
- Encodes them using ISO-8859-1
- Deflates them
- Emails them

I am running j2se1.6, geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec, geronimo-activation_1.1_spec.

I am talking to a Lotus Domino mail server, and my users have Outlook as their mail client.

I am following this code http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=30251

I create the mail message as MimeMultipart, I use ByteArrayDataSource() with a mimetype of 'application/zip'.

However when I view the email in Outlook, i see a load of inline base64 in the email message, like this;

> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
>
> Log files
> ------=_Part_0_14247437.1297692975078
> Content-Type: application/zip
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
>
> UEsDBBQACAAIAAdyTj4AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALAAAAbG9nIGVudHJpZXPsvWmT20aysPv5OGL+A965
> E+/1zCUp1IJNshyjpSXrHGs5Uns8cyyHg02iW7TYZA8XLcfh/36zAJBEkQCYCQLdTTk1I6urUZWV
> qDXzSRTQ7Tb6509fffv99MJ5E8/no+nkrvNkNhr2P3ecJ/HZbNmffXaE6DjSFcIR8q4I77qu8+q5
> 8/T5KRR883m+iC+dZ5Pz6V3nT185zqvZdLgcLJx/xDMjzVn9ue/8MBk978/exzOT7eVVPOsvRhOo
> ... trimmed for brevity

but I was hoping to see an attachment icon that I could click on.

Has anyone out there got this working properly? Got any suggestions?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be missing a

```
messageBodyPart.setDisposition(Part.ATTACHMENT);
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I discovered that my problem was apache geronimo; as soon as I switched to the Sun .jars, it magically started working ...